# ng-repeat with assocative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok trying to do what I should be a simple thing, I need to use ng-repeat with and assocative array. Totally lost on why this isn't working. It works perfectly with number based array keys, but not text characters.

```
function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [];
     $scope.friends[0] ='John',
     $scope.friends[1]= 'Mary',
     $scope.friends['aksnd']= 'Mike',
     $scope.friends['alncjd']= 'Adam',
     $scope.friends['skdnc']= 'Julie'
}

----

 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
         <span>{{friend}}</span>
     </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I also put together this is fiddle to show whats happening
http://jsfiddle.net/b9g0x7cw/4/

What am I doing wrong here? am I missing something obvious?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript we don't have associative arrays - we have objects:

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edut808r/

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).filter('removeAdam', function() {

})
.controller('HelloCntl', function($scope) {
    $scope.friends = {
        asdf:'John',
        dkfls: 'Mary',
        aksnd: 'Mike',
        alncjd: 'Adam',
        skdnc: 'Julie'
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I always knew that but never really delved into the differences, after some research I realized that assocative arrays are a no no (http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), and to use the object notation instead. Good to know! I never realized the array.length of an associative array is 0, which would be why angular was looking at me strange when I was yelling at it.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use associative arrays!**

http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

**2 BIG REASONS to not use Associative arrays**

- They have a length of 0.
- You are actually editing the properties of the array object and not the array key.

http://jsfiddle.net/3kppwhh6/1/

```
// using array
var friendsArr = [];
friendsArr['one']='one';
friendsArr['two']= 'two';

friendsArr.length; // 0
Object.keys(friendsArr).length; //2

//Using object
var friendsObj = {};
friendsObj['one'] ='one';
friendsObj['two'] = 'two';

Object.keys(friendsObj).length; //2
```